# NameError: name 'create_engine' is not defined in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am attempting to create a python script that connects to an SQLITE database and using SQLAlchemy to help with this.
I am still very early, but am trying to create a connection to a new database but keep getting this "create_engine" is not defined in SQLAlchemy error.
To try to simplify I opened a python terminal to try it... see below:

```
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 16:07:46) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlalchemy
>>> engine = create_engine('sqlite:///test.db')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'create_engine' is not defined
>>> print(sqlalchemy.__version__)
1.3.18
>>>
```

At this point I don't even know where to go looking for the problem.
I did a pip uninstall sqlalchemy then pip install sqlalchemy hoping this might help.

Comment: `engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///test.db')`

Comment: Alternatives: **(1)** `import sqlalchemy as sa; engine = sa.create_engine(...` **(2)** `from sqlalchemy import create_engine; engine = create_engine(...`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Gord Thompson. Changing this line:
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///test.db')
to:
engine = db.create_engine('sqlite:///test.db')
made it work!!